# Adding days on Selected dates on Datepicker Using PHP

Tags: php

I have a datepicker that is named *fromdate*

```
<div class="form-group">
<a>Date of Travel<input type="date" class="form-control" 
name="fromdate" 
style="width: 500px" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>"  required> 
</a>
</div>
```

And I have a field that is named *todate*

```
<div class="form-group">
<a>Estimated end of Travel<input type="text" class="form-control" 
name="todate"  style="width: 500px" readonly></a>
</div>
```

Now, everytime i select a specific date on *fromdate* datepicker I want to add 3 more days and that will be the value of *todate* (As you can see I specified it as readonly)

For Example:
*fromdate*=3/2/2019

*todate*=3/5/2019

I tried this one but it only gets the current date and adds 3 days.

```
<div class="form-group">
<a>Estimated end of Travel<input type="text" class="form-control" 
name="todate"  style="width: 500px" value="<?php
$rdate = "$fromdate";
echo date('M-d-Y', strtotime($rdate. ' + 3 days'));
?>"  readonly></a>
</div>
```

Comment: This can't be accomplished in PHP. You need to use JavaScript. In short, you create a trigger that fires every time someone selects a value in the fromdate field, and sets the value in the to field, that is three days after the fromdate value.

Comment: @dearsina oh i see